# Dragging Pictures to Taskbar Crashes Explorer.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash, taskbar

I have a problem when I drag pictures from anywhere in Firefox to the taskbar before into the active folder, it crashes explorer.exe on Windows 7.

What could be the cos of this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a crash dump and share it: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a rogue Shell Extension.

Try downloading [ShellViewEx](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and disabling your Drag and Drop Handlers one at a time.

Comment: Very well, I will give it a shot and report back.